# syntax error at or near "$1" in postgres

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I am trying to run the following function and I get the error "syntax error at or near "$1"
Could someone help me out fix this. Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vin_calc() RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r res%rowtype;
    i integer default 0;
    x  text;
    curs2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM res;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN curs2 

    LOOP
    if(x!=r.prod_grp_nm)
    i=0 
    end

     i:=i+1;

     if (i=1)
      update res set duration =0 where CURRENT OF curs2;

     elsif(i=2)
     update res set duration =1 where CURRENT OF curs2;

     elsif(i>=3)
     update res set gwma_duration =0.75*lag(res.duration,1)+(0.125*r.dur) where CURRENT OF curs2;
     end    

    x:=r.prod_grp_nm;      

    END LOOP;
    RETURN 'yes';
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

Comment: See [Conditionals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) in the plpgsql manual and notice the lack of `THEN` and `END IF` in your code does not conform to the valid forms.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.I am trying to use CURRENT OF curs2 to fetch the current row under the loop ?it doesnt work gives me an error 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: ...res set gwma_duration =0 where CURRENT OF  $1 . could you please help

Comment: Can you add the result of `select version();` to your question?

Comment: its "PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.3.2 build 1)

Comment: [Link to my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682574/get-column-value-of-previous-row-in-postgres)

Comment: So it's not postgresql, it's greenplum. It's based on postgresql but is a different, incompatible product. You want to refer to greenplum's documentation to check if it supports `WHERE CURRENT OF` in an update.

Comment: @user2569524 If you're using some incompatible PostgreSQL fork, **always say so**, don't just pretend it's PostgreSQL.