# Get Column value of previous row in postgres "cannot use window function in UPDATE"

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

When i is greater than or equal to 3, I am trying to fetch the previous row value of that column and trying to use it in the current row calculation and I have tried using Lag function to do so but was not successful,was getting the error as "cannot use window function in UPDATE". Could some one help me out.Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vin_calc() RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r res%rowtype;
    i integer default 0;
    x  text;
    curs2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM res;
BEGIN
open curs2;
   -- FOR r IN curs2 
  LOOP
  FETCH curs2 INTO r;
  exit when not found;

    if(x!=r.prod_grp_nm) then
    i:=0;
    end if;

     i:= i+1;

     if (i=1) then
      update res set duration =0 where 
      dur=r.dur and prod_grp_nm=r.prod_grp_nm and week_end=r.week_end;


     elsif(i=2) then
     update res set duration =1 where 
      dur=r.dur and prod_grp_nm=r.prod_grp_nm and week_end=r.week_end;


     elsif(i>=3) then
     update res set gwma_duration =0.875*lag(res.duration,1) over()+(0.125*r.dur) where 
      dur=r.dur and prod_grp_nm=r.prod_grp_nm and week_end=r.week_end;
     end if ;

    x:=r.prod_grp_nm;      

    END LOOP;
    RETURN 'yes';
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

Comment: You would have to wrap the window function into a sub-query and do an update join

Comment: I don't see any hint at an `ORDER BY` clause. Your whole operation is nonsense without sort order. [There is no "natural order"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095) in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ...

- `gwma_duration` and `duration` are supposed to be the same column and differ due to typos.
- You want to order by a column named `order_column`. Replace with your actual column(s).
- Your primary key columns is `res_id`. Replace with your actual column(s).

#### Put some lipstick on a pig:

Your procedural code repared and improved:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vin_calc()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r res%rowtype;
   i integer := 0;
   last_grp text;
BEGIN

FOR r IN
   SELECT * FROM res
LOOP
   IF last_grp <> r.prod_grp_nm THEN
      i := 1;
   ELSE
      i := i + 1;
   END IF;

   IF i < 3 THEN
      UPDATE res
      SET    duration = i - 1
      WHERE  dur = r.dur
      AND    prod_grp_nm = r.prod_grp_nm
      AND    week_end = r.week_end;

   ELSE
      UPDATE res r1
      SET    duration = r.dur * 0.125 + 
            (SELECT 0.875 * gwma_duration FROM res
             WHERE order_column < r1.order_column
             ORDER BY order_column
             LIMIT 1
            )  -- could be replaced with last_duration, analog to last_grp
      WHERE  r1.dur = r.dur
      AND    r1.prod_grp_nm = r.prod_grp_nm
      AND    r1.week_end = r.week_end;
   END IF;

   last_grp := r.prod_grp_nm;

   END LOOP;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Use the implicit cursor of a [`FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING). No need for unwieldy explicit cursor.
- Never quote the language name `plpgsql`, which is an identifier, not a string.
- Simplified your logic in several places.
- **Most importantly**, as the error message tells you, you can't use window functions in a `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`. I replaced it with a correlated subquery. But could probably be replaced with with `last_duration`, analog to `last_grp`: just remember the value from the last iteration.

### Proper solution

However, all of the above is very inefficient when you can do it in a **single `UPDATE` statement**:

```
UPDATE res r
SET    duration = CASE WHEN r0.rn < 3
                     THEN r0.rn - 1
                     ELSE r0.last_dur * 0.875 + r.dur * 0.125
                  END
FROM  (
   SELECT res_id, duration
        , row_number()  OVER (PARTITION BY prod_grp_nm ORDER BY order_column) AS rn
        , lag(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_grp_nm ORDER BY order_column) AS last_dur
   FROM res
   ) r0
WHERE  r.res_id = r0.res_id
```

- To be clear: you *can* use window functions in the `FROM` clause - at least in modern-day versions of Postgres.
- Use [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html), not <strike>`rank()`</strike> to be equivalent to your procedural code.